# What standard does JMeter use for HTML Assertion?

Tags: html, jmeter, validation

I added an HTML Assertion to my JMeter test.  It returned many errors and warnings for the html page.  I copied and pasted the same html code into the w3 validator and it returned much less warnings and errors.  The w3 validator was set to HTML5 and HTML 4.1 Strict on separate occasions.  I thought I would see the exact same errors / warnings in both instances.

I am not concerned about trying to figure out the exact differences.  I do not care much about that.  Both JMeter and the w3 validator are helping me clean up the code.  That is fine.

What I am wondering is what JMeter uses as its standard for the HTML Assertion?  Basically, what is it using to compare against when it points out the errors / warnings.

I also saw JTidy in JMeter.  I looked up JTidy which is just a java port of HTML Tidy.  But, I do not know what HTML Tidy uses as a standard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTMLAssertion class JavaDoc](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/HTMLAssertion.html)

`Assertion to validate the response of a Sample with Tidy.`

If you want more flexibility - try using [Beanshell Assertion](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) instead

Comment: Thank you for the reply.   I don't understand what that means.  Is "Sample with Tidy" the standard being used to compare against?  Also, I have no problem with the HTML Assertion.  I just want to know how Jmeter knows what is an error and what is a warning.  It had to compare against something, right?  The W3 validator has its own list for this.  Is JMeter using the same checks / verifications that the W3 validator uses?  Or does JMeter have its own list?  Or something else?